# SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 Sending 2 emails

Tags: reportingservices-2005

About 3 weeks ago, all of the recipients of our SSRS 2k5 automated email subscriptions began receiving duplicate report emails. Looks like all our automated reports are affected. Nothing looks to be an issue for SSRS.